# Image not clickable after loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have a set of images that are loaded via jQuery AJAX.  For some reason, my click handler won't trigger when it is clicked.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('img.delete_related_sub').click(function()
    {
    alert('testing');
    });

    //I added this part to test, because the above wasn't working...
    $(document).click(function(event)
    {
    alert(event.target.tagName+' '+event.target.className);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<img data-rsid="2" class="delete_related_sub" src="image.png" />
```

So my 2nd click handler alerts me with "IMG delete_related_sub".  But the first one isn't triggered.  The  is actually in a table that is actually in a pane run by bootstrap tabs, not sure if that'd actually help though.

Comment: Anytime you're adding something new into the DOM, try using event delegation. http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.delete_related_sub', function() {
    alert('testing');
});
```

Just replace `document` with a static parent of your image.

Comment: OMG that was it.  Why is this any different?  I use both all the time.

Comment: @PolishHurricane I explained "why" in my answer

Comment: The difference is that this method binds an event to the document. Each click bubbles up to the parents. Once it reaches the document, jQuery checks if the clicked element matches the selector. So the selector is checked agains the element at the time of the click, whereas using `click()` the event is bound to the elements matching the selector at the time of binding. Since the elements do not exist yet at that time, the `click()` won't work, while `on()` will.

Comment: @Chad I explained "why" in my comment

Comment: Just to clarify, it isn't that `.on()` works and `.click()` doesn't. It is that delegating the event works, and binding it directly to the non-existent element does not. `$('img.delete_related_sub').on('click', function() {})` still will not work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use this:

```
$("body").on('click', 'img.delete_related_sub', function() {
    alert('testing');
});
```

#### Or, in the `success:` give this:

```
$('img.delete_related_sub').click(function() {
    alert('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the line to bind the event runs before the element is added, try using

```
$(parent).on('click', 'img.delete_related_sub', function() {});
```

where the `parent` is a static element that will be there for sure. This works because the event is bound to an element that actually exists, then checks to match your selector. See [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more details.

Something like

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.delete_related_sub', function() {});
```

would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.delete_related_sub').live("click", function()
{
    alert('testing');
});
```

Use live event to listen clicks

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers." http://api.jquery.com/live/